# why did do i have to remove max-width in media-queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I was trying to make a website responsive, everything else was working but the screen didn't turn lime green instead it turned aquamarine. why does the
"and (max-width:px)" also need to be deleted

```
 body {
      background-color: aquamarine;
    }

    @media (max-width:480px){
      body{background-color:lightsalmon}
    }
    @media (min-width:481px) and (max-width:1200px){
      body{background-color:powderblue}
    }

    @media (min-width:1201px) and (max-width:1600px){
      body{background-color:limegreen}
    }


    @media (min-width:1601px)and (max-width:px){
      body{background-color:seagreen}
    }
```

before posting I got rid of "and (max-width:px)" and its ok, but why is just getting rid of lets say 2000 from 2000px not good enough

Comment: `(max-width:px)` is not a valid query.

Comment: `and (max-width:px)` is invalid

Comment: I don't think the question you asked is the question you meant to ask; could you double check? Because currently you're asking why doesn't an invalid media query work, which seems a little obvious although I do understand we can't all be fully aware of CSS syntax.

Comment: `@media (min-width:1601px)and (max-width:px){
      body{background-color:seagreen}
    }`

Is invalid. The max width would be ignored. Making the new rule override body background color when greater than 1601px.

Comment: If you don't have a ```max-width``` limit then don't state it at all. And if you are asking getting rid of 2000 from 2000px should give you the same result then I would ask you in which way ```2000px``` and ```px``` is equal?

Comment: Because CSS is a language, and languages have rules. If you speak the language and ignore the rules, you may be understood by some and not others. In this case, you are not understood by the most important listener of all; the browser.

Comment: I understand. just for context  I copied and pasted after the 2nd one  and just changed the color and max and min and since the last one the max was endless I thought leaving it blank would be ok, like misspelling/delating one thing would make it not show up